# Writing to CSV file choosing the column to write in

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to import the data from X (6 in this case) CSV Files containing some data about texts, and putting one specific row from each Document onto a new one, in such a way that they appear next to each other (export from document 1 on column 1, from the second document on row 2 and so on). I've been unsuccessful so far.

```py
# I have a list containing the path to all relevant files
files = ["path1", "path2", ...]

# then I tried cycling through the folder like this
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        for row on reader:
            # I'm interested in the stuff stored on Column 2
            print([row[2]])
# as you can see, I can get the info from the files, but from here 
# on, I can't find a way to then write that information on the 
# appropriate column of the newly created CSV file
```

I know how to open a writer, what I don't know is how to write a script that writes the info it fetches from the original 6 documents on a DIFFERENT COLUMN every time a new file is processed.

Comment: You can open writer like this
`with open(newfile, "w") as wcsvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(wcsvfile)
            for row on reader:
                 writer.writerow([row[2]])`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Answer (score 0):

```
# I have a list containing the path to all relevant files
files = ["path1", "path2", ...]
newfile = "newpath1"

# then I tried cycling through the folder like this
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        with open(newfile, "a") as wcsvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(wcsvfile)
            for row on reader:
                # I'm interested in the stuff stored on Column 2
                writer.writerow([row[2]])
```

Comment: Won't this create a new file for every file I process? I rather want to create a single file where everything is stored. Problem is, if I simply add a write() function on there, the script overwrites the old info with the new info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python

Comment: using open(newfile, "a")  will append data. Will not over ride

Answer (score 0):

The plan is to read each file, extract column 2, then append to a list of columns. Next, we can transpose the columns into rows using the `zip()` function. The final step is to write the rows out to a csv file. Here is a sample code:

```py
import csv

files = [
    "file1.csv",
    "file2.csv",
    "file3.csv",
]

columns = []
for file in files:
    with open(file) as stream:
        reader = csv.reader(stream)
        # row[1] is the second column
        columns.append([row[1] for row in reader])

with open("out.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
    writer = csv.writer(stream)
    # zip(*columns) transposes columns into rows
    writer.writerows(zip(*columns))
```

Notes

Since Python sequences are zero-based, the first cell in a row is `row[0]`, then the second cell is `row[1]`, not `row[2]`

Using zip to transpose: Here is an example of turning a list of columns (name, age) into rows:

```
columns = [["anna", "john", "ken"], [10, 11, 12]]
for row in zip(*columns):
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
('anna', 10)
('john', 11)
('ken', 12)
```